# Grails - is Spock plugin better than Testing plugin?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I am doing sample project and I need to better test my application, I heard Spock plugin is good testing plugin, but it was last updated in Oct 2012 around two years back.

Is it still the better one? Will it still work for latest Grails 2.4?

I am open to other testing solutions too.

Comment: [Click here to submit feedback about your question-asking experience.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258129)

Answer (score 2):

Spock is part of Grails now (since 2.3). You don't need to install the plugin.